# How do I prove that for every positive real number $a$, the equation $e^{-x} = ax$ has a real solution $x>0$?

Tags: solution-verification

How do I prove that for every positive real number $a$, the equation $^{-}=a$ has a real solution $x>0$?

What I tried: I tried moving everything to one side leaving the other side as $0$. Then I drew up a graph of the $e^{-x}$ and the $ax$ line (where a is some positive gradient) as separate curves. My teacher suggested I substitute $f(0)$ and $f(1/a)$ into the equation to see the sign of the function $f(x)= ax- ^{-x}$. But I don't know how that helps. In general, does anyone have tips for proving this sort of thing, and what category of proof is this?

Answer (score 0):

$f(0) = -1 < 0$, $f(1/a) = 1 - e^{1/a} > 0$, and $f$ is continuous. Thus, $f$ is continuous function that has values of different signs on $[0, 1/a]$, and so, by [Bolzano's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), it has a zero in this interval.

In general, I would start by checking values at ends: in equation $e^{-x} = ax$, if $x = 0$ then left side is bigger (as it's positive and right is zero), but if $x$ is very large, then right side is bigger (as it grows, while left side goes to $0$). As both sides are continuous, there will be an intersection.

(the second paragraph is essentially the same as the first, just without finding explicit value where right side is bigger)

Comment: why woudl we be checking the ends though?

Comment: Because Bolzano's theorem says so: if $f$ is continuous, $f(x) > 0$ and $f(y) < 0$ then $f(z) = 0$ for some $z \in [x, y]$.